# An Apk decompiling and recompiling not working

Tags: android

I was trying to translate non-English to English in strings.xml, but after the apk was recompiled and signed with AndroidMultitool and run, the message said "It is not an official version now", then it exited automatically. I even tried to just decompile it (didn't touch any files), and recompile right away, it popped up same message and exited.

Comment: are you signing the recompiled version with the same key as the original?

Comment: It is not my apk, I just wanted to use it comfortably with the language. I don't know the original signature.

Comment: in that case Marco Aciemo's answer is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because when an application is released it will be signed by the developer and every version released **should** be released with the same signature or it will not be recognized as the same application.

If it's your application, well just recompile it with the same certificate.

If it's not by you, just don't decompile the APK, if the developer want ask to him if he wants help in translate the app.

You can release the APK around but it will not be see like the original, and if some users already have the application installed, Android will notify the user with a message about the different certificate.

Comment: Accept this answer if it helped you. (The V symbol)